# Home component not rendered even the condition is met

Tags: reactjs

I'm building a React app and trying to render the home component at localhost:3000. In this app, Main is rendered by the App component, and I want Main to render Home component if the user is currently at localhost:3000. The code below is my main.js where I do conditional rendering. However, the Home component was not rendered and it was just a blank page when I was at localhost:3000 using either approach. I am wondering how I can fix this issue. Thanks!

```
class Main extends Component {
  render() {
    const HomePage = () => {
      return <Home />;
    };

    const WaitingRoomPage = () => {
      return <WaitingRoom />;
    };

    ......

    //1st approach
    let home;
    if (window.location.href === "http://localhost:3000") {
      home = <Home />;
    }

    //2nd approach
    const home = window.location.href === "http://localhost:3000" ? <Home /> : null;


    return (
      <div>
        <Switch>
          <Route path='/home' component={HomePage} />
          <Route path='/physics' component={PhysicsPage} />
          <Route path='/startstream' component={StartStreamPage} />
          <Route path='/stream' component={StreamPage} />
          <Route path='/signup' component={SignUpPage} />
          <Route path='/login' component={LogInPage} />
          <Route path='/profile' component={ProfilePage} />
          <Route path='/waitingroom' component={WaitingRoomPage} />
          <Route path='/streamingplaza' component={StreamingPlazaPage} />
          <Route path='/settings' component={SettingsPage} />
        </Switch>

        //Conditionally rendering Home component
        {home}

      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default Main;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The path for plain `localhost:3000` is `/`, not `/home`. You can fix this issue by changing the `path` for the `HomePage` from `"/home"` to `"/"` and add the prop `exact` (boolean) to that `Route`. The `exact` prop tells the router to only match if the window's path is exactly `"/"`, not just if it starts with `"/"` (if you leave this out, only the `HomePage` component will render and none of the others). If you'd like to still support the `/home` route, you can just add another route that meets the changes I've described above.

After this, you can remove your 1st and 2nd attempt code and the part of the returned component with `{home}`.

Here's a full example:

```js
class Main extends Component {
  render() {
    const HomePage = () => {
      return <Home />;
    };

    const WaitingRoomPage = () => {
      return <WaitingRoom />;
    };

    // ...

    return (
      <div>
        <Switch>
          <Route exact path='/' component={HomePage} />
          <Route path='/home' component={HomePage} />
          <Route path='/physics' component={PhysicsPage} />
          <Route path='/startstream' component={StartStreamPage} />
          <Route path='/stream' component={StreamPage} />
          <Route path='/signup' component={SignUpPage} />
          <Route path='/login' component={LogInPage} />
          <Route path='/profile' component={ProfilePage} />
          <Route path='/waitingroom' component={WaitingRoomPage} />
          <Route path='/streamingplaza' component={StreamingPlazaPage} />
          <Route path='/settings' component={SettingsPage} />
        </Switch>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much! If the project is in production mode and I include "homepage": "http://mywebsite.com" in package.json, will <Route exact path='/' component={HomePage} /> causes the Home component to be rendered at mywebsite.com as well?

Comment: Yep, doing the routes in this way will make it work regardless of the host.